# Typescript generics with different types inside angle brackets

Tags: typescript

when it comes to something like this in TS generics: `function fn<T, U>(...)`, i.e. a couple of types inside angle brackets, what do they really mean? What's the purpose of having more than one generic type inside `<>`? Params can be either `T` or `U`?

Comment: A lot of the time, generics are not meant to be provided as parameters but are assigned to something in the function signature, such as `fn<A, B, C>(arg1: A, arg2:B)` for further manipulation. Why more than 1? Well there can be more than one type you want to make generic. Maybe its arg1, arg2, maybe its values in an object arg, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The types defined inside the angle brackets are separate. The definition `function fn<T, U>(...)` means that `fn` function requires 2 type parameters - `T` and `U` - and that's it. They can be the same type at the context of `fn`'s consumer, but are parameters defined as `T` and `U` in the `fn` function's context.

A use case for having more than one generic type could be the [`Pick` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) which is a TypeScript builtin utility type:

> ## `Pick<Type, Keys>`
>
> Constructs a type by picking the set of properties `Keys` (string literal or union of string literals) from `Type`.
>
> ###### [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoHsAm7kG8BQyyYwYANhAFzIDOYUoA5gNyHKYQ0IMAOJ6IanQYgWbBOgC2PCpEzUARunQU4IVgF98+MAE8eKDNgAKUCADdgEAO7IAvMmPAEAawA8R9ABpkAIhLkEL7IAD5+EtKyEJi+AHys+BIgdMRY6NSephZWtg4ERAEU1L4AwqogyFDKkr5e4lIyEHLU8GQ0EHUaCWBprAD0fcgAegD8QA)
>
> ```
> interface Todo {
>   title: string;
>   description: string;
>   completed: boolean;
> }
>
> type TodoPreview = Pick<Todo, "title" | "completed">;
>
> const todo: TodoPreview = {
>  title: "Clean room",
>  completed: false,
> };
> ```

We pass 2 types to `Pick`:

1. `Type` - which in this case is `Todo`, and
2. `Keys` - which in this case is `"title" | "completed"`.
   Notice how the definition says that `Keys` is either a string literal or union of string literals. That means that `Keys` would be defined as `Keys extends string`, but is actually defined as `Keys extends keyof Type` - restricting the type passed to `Pick` as `Keys` to only the `string`s that are keys of `Type`.

What we achieve is `TodoPreview` which is basically a subset of `Todo`, consisting only of the keys `"title"` and `"completed"`.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose is to constrain the signature according to those types.

Here is some good info from the documentation:
[TypeScript Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-type-parameters-in-generic-constraints)

Essentially, when you have something like the following, you're just trying to relate all the types together in some way. This code would just check 3 differently typed parameters and return if all of them are truthy.

```js
function myFunc<A, B, C>(param1: A, param2: B, param3: C): boolean {
  return !!param1 && !!param2 && !!param3;
}
```

Because the types are generic, you can't be too restrictive because the whole point of generics is to give consumers flexibility. This works great when you use the `keyof` and `typeof` syntax to relate one type to the other.